# How to get week number since epoch? Like millis?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, datetime, timezone

I'm modeling a weekly reporting store in DynamoDb.

I'm thinking the best way to identify the report-records is by their respective week number since 1970. Much like epoch milliseconds.

Therefore:

1. How to get to the current week number since 1970?
2. How to get start and end dates given such week number?

Considering all the possible edge cases I might not be aware of, like daylight savings and similar, I'm quite uncomfortable trying to solve this.

---

Clarifications:

- Week starts Sunday night at midnight.
- In order to work out the exact time, the function 1. receives the desired UTC offset in minutes. (I'm open to suggestions here)

Comment: To get started on this project, I suggest you work out in detail what you mean by the start of a week. Is it midnight each Monday in Central European local time? Is it midnight each Sunday in UTC? Are you in a jurisdiction where the daylight time switchover rules have changed since 1970? This stuff is surprisingly hard to do perfectly.

Comment: @O.Jones good points. Question updated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

UNIX time is in seconds since January 1, 1970.

That day was a Thursday. So, midnight Sunday UTC on the zeroth week of the UNIX epoch (which started on on that date) occurred at -345 600 seconds in UNIX time. Midnight Sunday in the first week occurred at 259 200 seconds in UNIX time.

The UNIX time calendar contains no leap seconds, so each week is precisely 7 days, 604 800 seconds long.

Therefore, to get the week number in UTC from a UNIX time, do this.

```
(unixTime + 345600) div 604800
```

Javascript timestamps are UNIX timestamps in milliseconds. So, in JS, that's

```
Math.floor ((jsTimestamp + 345_600_000) / 604_800_000)
```

To get the Javascript timestamp of Sunday midnight back from the week number, reverse the operation.

```
(weekNumber * 604_800_000) + 345_600_000
```

This is all in UTC time.

Comment: Thank you mister! Please give me a day or two to review. Didn't expect an answer so soon : ) Awesome catch with 1970 not starting on Monday!

Comment: Week numbers typically start from 1, this assumes the first week is 0.

Comment: @RobG We could just +1 then? 

Comment: Bonus point for showing me I can use underscores as a thousands separator. Who knew?